# Error Creating Controller With Custom Type using Entity Framework MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, complextype

I'm trying to create a controller with a model that has custom types in it...

I have a main class with ID and a type 'Work', where I declared three properties, one of which relies on the other two. Then I created a dbset type. Are my mapping properties incorrect?

I am getting the following error: 
There was an error running the selected code generator: "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Stack.Models.Work'". the property sum is not a declared property on type Math. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore Method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure it is a valid primitive property.

```
namespace stack.Models
{
public class Work
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Work ()
    {
        this.Maths = new Math();
    }



    public Math Maths { get; set; }


}


[ComplexType]
public class Math
{

    public int first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }
    public int sum
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return first + second;
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }
}


public class WorkDBContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Work> Working { get; set; }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Work>()
                    .Property(c => c.Maths.first).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Work>()
                    .Property(c => c.Maths.second).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Work>()
                    .Property(c => c.Maths.sum).IsRequired();


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: `sum` is a calculated, read-only property so it can't be mapped to a database field.  Have you tried the suggested `[NotMapped]` attribute?  Also, why are you setting a calculated value to `isRequired`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum is not a simple type (column in the database) it is a data function(calculated from other properites), you do not have to store it in the database.

```
[ComplexType]
public class Math
{

    public int first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] 
    public int sum
    {
        get
        {
           return first + second;
        }
    }
}
```

Remove this line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Work>()
                    .Property(c => c.Maths.sum).IsRequired();
```